# Не работает проверка которая проверяет массив и возвращает число, которое показывает сколько раз число встречается в массиве. PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Искомое число $sum = 7 Массив (7,7,7,5,4,5,8) $arr - массив. На выходе должен получить 3, так как чисел 7 в массиве 3. Как реализовать?

```
  function t2($num, $arr)
{
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); $i++){
    if ($num === $arr[$i]){
        $i++;
    }
}
   return $i;
}
```

Comment: Какие у вас сложности с этим возникли? На каком моменте запоролись?

Comment: по простому: Делаете цикл, если встречаете нужную цифру - прибавляете в специальном счётчике. после цикла смотрите что в счётчике

Comment: Проблема возникла в выборе, либо через цикл либо через функцию. Ниже предложили вариант попробую с циклом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для новичков:

1. Делаем счётчик. Инициализируем его нулём.
2. Делаем цикл по массиву. Если число на итерации равно заданному числу, то прибавляем значение счётчика на 1.
3. **После** цикла смотрим значение счётчика

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: А другое решение помогло хоть? А то тоже было 'попробую' но так и неизвестно)

Comment: Если имеете в виду про другой вопрос то да, я тут новичок поэтому не знаю что надо сделать чтобы было видно что "помогло".Попробую оазобраться))

Comment: @KoRn если ответ помог - то как правило тыкают на галочку, рядом с ответом, который помог. Если репутация позволяет - кто-то ещё стрелочку вверх нажимает (обычно когда репутации больше 15)

Comment: Спасибо разобрался. Я сделал так     $x = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); $i++){
    if ($arr[$i] === $num ){
        $x += 1 ;
    }
}
  return $x;
}

Comment: @KoRn отлично. только не `<=`, а `<` потому что иначе будет выход за границы массива.

Comment: Точно, не учел))